# MySQL query grouping in a fancy way

Tags: mysql, select

I need a mysql query who want to do this

```
initial data
id | from_id | to_id | route_id | price
1  | 360     | 415   | 204      | 100
2  | 372     | 458   | 204      | 100
3  | 395     | 372   | 204      | 100
4  | 395     | 372   | 204      | 100
5  | 395     | 372   | 205      | 100
6  | 395     | 372   | 204      | 100
7  | 395     | 458   | 210      | 100
8  | 395     | 458   | 210      | 100

result data
id | from_id | to_id | route_id | price
1  | 395     | 372   | 204      | 100      // because his periodicity is 3
2  | 395     | 458   | 210      | 100      // because his periodicity is 2
3  | 395     | 372   | 205      | 100
4  | 360     | 415   | 204      | 100
5  | 372     | 458   | 204      | 100
```

Is something like that

```
SELECT * FROM myTable GROUP BY from_id,to_id,route_id
```

but i don't know how to add COUNT or MAX and ORDER BY
Thanks

Comment: Look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) for the syntax of the `SELECT` statement and [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) for `COUNT`, [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) for `MAX` and [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) for `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      min( id ) FirstID, 
      from_id, 
      to_id, 
      route_id, 
      max(price) MaxPrice, 
      count(*) as Periodicity
   from 
      myTable 
   GROUP BY 
      from_id,
      to_id,
      route_id
```

Your final table of IDs looks more like a sequential, but that doesn't correlate with original data and doesn't appear to serve any purpose otherwise.